# TypeLoadException with VisualStudioConfiguration.SetupConfigurationClass asp.net core

Tags: c#, npm, asp.net-core, macos-sierra

Suddenly I got this error after building my asp.net core application.

I did not change any things of **c#** code ( only script calls in 3 **cshtml** ), I was working on my **scss** and **typescripts** with webpack.

This is the error :

```
Could not load type 'VisualStudioConfiguration.SetupConfigurationClass' from 
assembly 'Askmethat.Askmycar.WebApp, 
Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'.
```

If someone have an idea...

**EDIT :**

One of my nom-package (**node-gyp**) have a file with a lot of warning in **Find-VS2017.cs**

**EDIT 2 :**

The error comes from node-sass... So I need to find the way to exclude a directory from compilation with MSBuild

Thanks :D

Comment: I got this error suddenly, too. How'd you fix?

Comment: You can delete the files. I open an issue in asp.net core & gyp repo but they not track it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For me, I made it so that the `node_modules` folder is ignored. I added this to my .csproj file:

```
<ItemGroup>
    <Compile Remove="node_modules/**" />
    <Content Remove="node_modules/**" />
    <EmbeddedResource Remove="node_modules/**" />
    <None Remove="node_modules/**" />
</ItemGroup>
```

Comment: Good solution :)